# How to access LESS variables in styles.less from LESS files inside components in Angular 6 or 7?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, less

Angular version 7.0.0
The folder structure is what you get when you run "ng new " which is

This is my styles.less file

```css
@personal-black: #0000;
```

and this is my app.component.less file

```css
#personal-style-scheme {
    color: @personal-black;
}
```

```css
<h1 id="personal-style-scheme">
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
</h1>
```

The error I get is:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/app/app.component.less Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js): #personal-style-scheme { color: @personal-black; ^ Variable @personal-black is undefined in C:\Users\Sameer\Documents\my-app\src\app\app.component.less (line 2, column 11)

I don't understand why the less variable @personal-black is not accessible by the component's less file.

Angular.json File

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "less"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.less"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.less"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "my-app-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-app"
}
```

Comment: Hi could you share your `angular.json` file

Comment: Edited the answer to include it

Comment: You need to import the variable into your app.component.less file. 
@import "styles.less"; ## <- At the top of that file.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the solution commented by [@jriver27](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4560600/jriver27), but I got the following error as I was referring material theme css using relative path.

> ERROR in Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):  Error: Failed to find
>   '../../~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css'

I fixed the issue using 'reference' option of the import statement. You can find the more details [here](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-atrules-feature-reference).

```
@import (reference) "../../styles.less";
```